# Dos funciones se interfieren al usar método .replace()

Tags: javascript, funciones, replace

En el código a continuación pretendo usar el método `.replace()` de dos formas distintas y en ningún caso consigo el cambio de texto deseado:

1. El evento `onclick` del botón llama a la función `myFunction` pero ésta no reemplaza **Windows** por **ZorinOS**.
2. El evento `onmouseover` llama a la función `mySecondFunction`, pero ésta no reemplaza el valor del `span` al que le he asignado el correspondiente `id="demo2"`.

Me surgen dos dudas:

1. Al comentar la segunda función, el evento `onclick` del botón sí que activa `myFunction`. ¿Por qué sucede esto? ¿Cómo interfiere la segunda función con la primera?
2. ¿Por qué `mySecondFunction` no cambia el `span` con `id="demo2"` cuando comento la primera función?

### JavaScript String Methods

Replace "Windows" with "ZorinOS" in the next paragraph:

Please visit Windows!

Try it

Please visit Windows!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript String Methods</h2>

<p>Replace "Windows" with "ZorinOS" in the next paragraph:</p>

<p id="demo">Please visit Windows!</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>Please visit <span id="demo2" onmouseover="mySecondFunction()">Windows</span>!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
  let text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  text.replace("Windows","ZorinOS");
}

function mySecondFunction(){
  let text2 = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
  text2.replace("Windows","ZorinOS";)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrigiendo lo que marco en los comentarios se debería solucionar. Tienes un `;)`cuando debería ser `);`.

```
function mySecondFunction(){
  let text2 = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
  text2.replace("Windows","ZorinOS";)
  /* El error:                     ^^ */
}


function mySecondFunction() {
    let text2 = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
    text2.replace("Windows", "ZorinOS");
    /* Cambiado                      ^^ */
}
```

Comment: Menudo error el mío… de traca! Muchas gracias por la corrección!

Comment: @IvanSanczewski nos pasa a muchos. El tema es que lo has podido solucionar. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un `;` de mas. Debería funcionar sin problemas.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let text = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    text.replace("Windows", "ZorinOS");
}

function mySecondFunction() {
  let text2 = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML =
    text2.replace("Windows", "ZorinOS")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript String Methods</h2>

  <p>Replace "Windows" with "ZorinOS" in the next paragraph:</p>

  <p id="demo">Please visit Windows!</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p>Please visit <span id="demo2" onmouseover="mySecondFunction()">Windows</span>!</p>

</body>

</html>
```

## Edición

---

Javascript siempre requiere `;`. Cuando los omites, una función interna los agrega, pero en ocasiones (y cuando conoces poco del lenguaje) lo interpreta mal. Aqui un ejemplo:

```js
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = a+b;
(a+b).toString()
//Debe salir 3
console.log(c)
```

```js
const a = 1
const b = 2
const c = a+b
(a+b).toString()

console.log(c)
```

Este último caso en particular se corrige así:

```js
const a = 1
const b = 2
const c = a+b
;(a+b).toString()

console.log(c)
```

Al final, es tu decisión, pero hay que entender que los semicolons si o sí existen. No es como python, que naturalmente fue creado sin estos. Javascript ha ido cambiando para ser más aceptado y algunas cosas han sido muy buenas, pero otras tanto no. Esto lo saque de este [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/to-semicolon-or-not-to-semicolon-a2e337827bcb)

Comment: Gracias por la corrección! Me surge una pequeña duda: ¿Cuál es la mejor praxis para la última línea de una **función**: omitir el ultimo `;`, que como propones soluciona el problema, o ponerlo siempre, como propone @OscarR?

Comment: Edite mi respuesta para constestarte.

Comment: Muy agradecido por el código de ejemplo y el artículo!! :)